# Comparing numbers in text fields with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.d = { v1: '100', v2: '20' };
    });
```

Template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      1: <input type="text" ng-model="d.v1" />
      2: <input type="text" ng-model="d.v2" />
      <h4>{{d.v1}} &lt; {{d.v2}} = {{d.v1 < d.v2}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GDfxd/292/

This example incorrectly shows that 100 is less than 20. Any advice how to    make this comparison numeric ?

Comment: because they are `strings` not `numbers`, you need to convert before compare [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GDfxd/293/)

Comment: Make `type="number"`

Comment: @Jag try entering some numbers in inputs, they will be string type again

Answer (score 1):

the type of your variable is "text" you have to change it to "number" to get the right result.

Answer (score 0):

All that you need is to **compare numbers instead of strings**

Here is the working snippet:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.d = { v1: 100, v2: 20 };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      1: <input type="text" ng-model="d.v1" />
      2: <input type="text" ng-model="d.v2" />
      <h4>{{d.v1}} &lt; {{d.v2}} = {{d.v1 < d.v2}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I just added an Eval function and left everything else the same!

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.d = { v1: '100', v2: '20' };
        $scope.eval = function() {
           return (parseInt($scope.d.v1, 10) < parseInt($scope.d.v2, 10));
        }
    });
```

Template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      1: <input type="text" ng-model="d.v1" />
      2: <input type="text" ng-model="d.v2" />
      <h4>{{d.v1}} &lt; {{d.v2}} = {{eval()}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jc4vvp86/2/